# Runtime error of NoClassDefFoundError when a eclipse plugin depends on other eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have an eclipse plugin project `com.prosseek.asttest`, and I spin off a new plugin project `com.prosseek.impactAnalyzer` that has one class `CallHierarchyGenerator.java`. Now asttest project depends on impactAnalyzer project. I had no choice but to make impactAnalyzer project eclipse plugin as it uses JDT library.

After setting up the build path in  `com.prosseek.asttest`, it builds without a problem.

[image]

However, when I execute the plugin, I got an error missing `CallHierarchyGenerator.java` class.

[image]

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running this as an OSGI or Eclipse Application, you need to explicity export packages as available to other plugins as by default they are not. Open your manifest editor in plugin 1. Click on the runtime tab and add the packages as "Exported" then the class loader in blugin 2 will be able to find it.

Also looks like you might be doing the class path configuration wrong. in plugin 2 make sure you add plugin 1 as a dependency in the dependencies tab of the manifest editor. Looks like you are doing a dependency configuration as if it were a regular java application

Comment: Could you care to check my other post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13983819/errors-in-exporting-eclipse-deployable-plug-ins-and-fragments ? The issue is that with my project A (eclipse plugin) depends on project B and C (they are just Java projects), everything works fine in eclipse IDE, but I can't export plugin.

Comment: Added an answer, take a look at my comments.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Duncan's answer, I could fix this issue.

### Export packages in `impactAnalyzer`

[image]

Actually I didn't add it manually, but it's already exported, as (I guess) I did it with Quick Assist automatically.

### Required Plug-ins

I had to Add `com.prosseek.impactAnalyzer` in the dependecies.
[image]

### Run configuration update

I had one more step to do, I had to open run configuration to `add required plug-ins`.

[image]

### Export the plugin

When exporting the `asttest` plugin, I also had to export `impactAnalyzer` also.

[image]
[image]