# Issue when exporting eclipse plugin with linked folder

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a eclipse plugin project (LSclipse), and two java projects (I'll call them A, B) that LSclipse uses.

Two projects are Linked Folder in LSclipse, and everything works fine in eclipse IDE.

[image]

When I tried to export the project as eclipse plug in, I got an error.

[image]

The error messages are caused by those types in the A, B projects are not properly referenced.

```
2. ERROR in   /Users/smcho/Dropbox/smcho/workspace/seal2/LSclipse/src/lsclipse/LSDiffRunner.java (at line 61)
    import edu.washington.cs.induction.OnePipeLineScript;
       ^^^
The import edu cannot be resolved
```

I unzip the partially generated jar file and found that all the class files in A, B are compiled correctly.

The Package Explorer shows the packages in A, B without any issue other than blank folders.

[image]

I added A, B in the `build.property`,

[image]

and now I have this error saying those directories do not exist beneath LSclipse directory.

[image]

What's wrong with this?

Comment: Maybe i'm wrong: Did you added them in the build.properties "bin.includes" ? Otherwise they will not be exported in the binary-build.

Comment: I added them in "bin.included". Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why Linked Foler works, but I could use symbolic link to get the working exported  plugins.

I also think exporting jars for the dependent projects first, and then include them as library can be another way to solve this issue.

Reference - [Errors in exporting eclipse deployable plug-ins and fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13983819/errors-in-exporting-eclipse-deployable-plug-ins-and-fragments)

Answer (score 0):

For reference in case someone comes here from google (like I did), the related bug in Eclipse is [66177](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=66177). If you want it fixed, go and upvote it.

(ironically, one comment in the bug was made 2004 and said "To be honest it is unlikely to be fixed in a near future.", very true :) )